# Getting Error in Mysql related to DPKG dependency management

Tags: mysql, vagrant

I am getting the below error while trying to install Mysql with a shell script.

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-community-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 5.6.35-1ubuntu14.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-community-server
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried to purge the dependencies of mysql using the link https://askubuntu.com/questions/707309/problems-installing-mysql-server

Nothing seemed to have worked so far.
I am trying to install it with vagrant and ubuntu/trusty64

Comment: maybe you should add your shell script